# Opencart Journal Theme saving issue

Tags: php, module, save, opencart, journal

I have an OC 3.0.3.8 with Journal 3.1.12 theme. When i'm on the "Skins" menu, edit anything and click to save nothing happen. The save button just spinning around. Other journal3 menus works great.

[image: Skins menu]